# How to simplify angular-ui-router nested state with many combinations of sub states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Here is the mock up of my app:

[image]

"Left side bar" is for directories, while the "main content" is for files. The files are enumerated from the selected directory ([list mode]).

The "left side bar" is to be reused for 2 other purposes:

1. display form to create new directory ([create mode])
2. display form to edit selected directory ([edit mode])

Similarly, the main content could also be in [list mode], [edit mode], and [create mode]. So, in total there would be 3 x 3 possible combinations.

Using ng-switch, this one can be modeled quite easily.

```
<div class="left-bar">
  <div ng-switch on="directory.mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="list"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="create"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="edit"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div ng-switch on="files.mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="list"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="create"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="edit"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I wish to model this using angular-ui router. I am new to angular-ui, and the state model I could think of now is something like:

```
.state('main.folder-list.file-list', views: {'left-sidebar':{templateUrl:'directory-list.html'}, 'main-content':{templateUrl:'file-list.html'}})
.state('main.folder-list.file-edit', ...)
.state('main.folder-list.file-create', ...)
.state('main.folder-edit.file-list', ...)
.state('main.folder-edit.file-edit', ...)
.state('main.folder-edit.file-create', ...)
.state('main.folder-create.file-list', ...)
.state('main.folder-create.file-edit', ...)
.state('main.folder-create.file-create', ...)
```

One important requirement: when the mode of "left side bar" is switched, the content of "main content" shouldn't be changed (it should still be in the same mode as before), and vice versa.

How to simplify that?

Answer (score 0):

First think first, remember that `angular-ui router` able to handle nested state. I usually use `.state('root')`, `.state('root.app')`, `.state('root.app.specific')`, etc. With that characteristics of `angular-ui router`, we can simply set `$scope` at `root` state like `$scope.data = { status: 'ok' }` and in root's child, we still able to call that `$scope.data`.

Also if your `create`, `list`, `edit` is a generic "class" or singleton. You can also make it simple using `angular controller inheritance` in your controller type `$controller('[parent-controller]', {$scope: $scope});`. So your `parent-controller`'s `$scope` like method that they have etc. will be able to called inside your `new controller`'s `$scope`. `Angular-ui router`'s nested state is similar to this. For example:

```
Application.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('AdminCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
}]);
```

In that example my `AppCtrl` will have the `AdminCtrl`'s `$scope`.